# perl DateTime incorrect timezone offset

Tags: perl, datetime, centos

I have several servers running under centos 6.3 and I faced issue that perl module DateTime treats Europe/Moscow timezone as UTC+3

```
 [ulan@rt-virtual ~]$ perl -MDateTime -e 'print DateTime->now()->set_time_zone("Europe/Moscow"), "\n";'
 2013-12-19T11:11:38
```

but in fact it is UTC+4 and system tools like zdump or date work correctly

```
 [ulan@rt-virtual ~]$ zdump Europe/Moscow
 Europe/Moscow  Thu Dec 19 12:11:47 2013 MSK
```

I updated tzdata and DateTime module but it didn't help.
How can I amend this?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you check the contents of DateTime/TimeZone/Europe/Moscow.pm file (and compare with [this one](https://metacpan.org/source/DROLSKY/DateTime-TimeZone-1.63/lib/DateTime/TimeZone/Europe/Moscow.pm))?

Comment: there are quite a lot differencies. Seems that it was bug in DateTime. I installed last module version from CPAN instead of the one from repository and issue has gone.

Comment: though your assumption is right. I just replaced  DateTime/TimeZone/Europe/Moscow.pm with one from your link (on another server) and it also works.

Comment: The problem, I suppose, is that Russians stopped following DST routines in 2011 - and that change is not reflected in the repository's most recent version. And yes, reinstalling from CPAN should fix it.

Comment: @raina77ow, Make that a simple answer so this can be Answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `DateTime` module is doing its magic by following the rules specified in the `TimeZone` modules specific for each timezone. For `Europe/Moscow`, the module's is `DateTime::TimeZone::Europe::Moscow`. The problem is all the files are generated automatically corresponding to the rules existing when a specific version of DateTime module is released.

In this case one very important change - Russia's stopping following DST routines in 2011 - wasn't obviously reflected in that file. So updating - either the whole module or only the relevant [TimeZone part](https://metacpan.org/source/DROLSKY/DateTime-TimeZone-1.63/lib/DateTime/TimeZone/Europe/Moscow.pm) - should have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your systems [tzfile(5)](http://man.he.net/man5/tzfile), using [DateTime::TimeZone::Tzfile](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime%3a%3aTimeZone%3a%3aTzfile). Not only does it perform better than DateTime::TimeZone it also removes the need to have redundant data that needs to be in sync.

```
$tz = DateTime::TimeZone::Tzfile->new('/etc/localtime');
$dt = DateTime->now(time_zone => $tz);
```